# Create own string using const char * vs char *

Tags: c++, char, constants, c-strings

I want to create my own string storage (class) and I know something about `const char *` and `char *`.

This is a part of my source:

```
class str_n
{
private:

    char * _str;

public:

    str_n(const char * str)
    {
          std::size_t Read_len = strlen(str);
          _str = (char *) malloc(Read_len + 1);
          memcpy(_str, str, Read_len + 1);
    }
};
```

I used `char *` and `const char *` for my `_str` and I know if I use `const char *` I need to copy it to `char *` whlie I want to use some other functions inside of my class and also using `const char *` is faster (very faster (about 2x)) than `char *` to save the `const char * param` content.

Now my question: **If you want to create new string storage, you use `const char *` or `char *`?**

Comment: Simple: use `const` if the field is no intended to be modified in any way during object life time, if not don't.

Comment: we have changes during the program ! i heard about const that changes have no problem (you can change the content but not the pointer) so why you said that ?

Comment: focus on object's lifetime... Are your `str_n` objects mutable or not? If not then use `const`.

Comment: 100% is mutable but as i said you can also change the const content !

Comment: Note that `memcpy` don't convert anything...

Comment: i know ... i changed my code

Comment: Also note that you could have used `std::strcpy` instead of `memcpy` with the `+1`

Comment: why? they both are same !

Comment: @USEBase they will always be the same for c-strings, but that function exists solely to copy c-strings, so why not use it?  It leaves a little room for interpretation on the user's end when they see a `memcpy` with a `+1`

Comment: Changing the content of a const char? How? You can change the pointer, by doing something like `_str = "new string";`, but that is not changing the content. `_str[5] = 'a';` would not compile for const char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `char *`, if your `str_n` is mutable. You're wrong on the part that const content is modifiable. For example, this:

```
const char *foo = "foo";
foo[0] = 'a';
```

won't compile. Trying to circumvent it with const_cast is not a viable option:

```
const_cast<char *>(foo)[0] = 'a';
```

as it is undefined behavior, and usually crashes, as `foo` is put in read-only memory.

So, if your string is mutable, you **must** copy the contents of `str` (the parameter for the constructor) in your example (you don't have the option of using `const char *` as storage, and omitting the copy to make your program faster -- I suppose you meant "2x faster" because you omitted the copy).

A note: you should use `new` instead of `malloc`, it is more c++-ish (you won't need to cast to `char *` the result of `new char[...]`)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `std::string`

```
class str_n {
public:
    str_n(const char * str_in) : str{str_in} {}
private:
    std::string str;
};
```

you can fetch the c string from a C++ string with the `.c_str()` method

Comment: no i don't want to use string ... i want to make something like string !

Comment: @USEBase your solution looks to be optimal then, unless you want to worry about optimizing your string class, just remember to add a destructor and default initialize the pointer to `nullptr`